# Локализация приложение

Tags: java, android, локализация

Надо прописать условие, которое зависит от локализации, т.е если регион RU, то человек будет переходить по одной ссылке, а если любой другой регион, то по другой ссылке. Как написать это условие?

Comment: Получить локализацию и проверить через if - else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из того, что я понял - тут 2 варианта:

1. Получить текущую локаль и уже решать что нужно в зависимости от нее

   ```
   getResources().getConfiguration().locale
   ```
2. Если вопрос только в ссылках - можно положить их в ресурсы для разных локалей и получать через

   ```
   getString(R.string.your_url_string_id)
   ```

В таком случае никакие условия писать не надо - Андроид сам возьмет нужную строку для локали